General solution that have the rectangular function as amplitude of the Fourier transform
The sinc function has as Fourier transform the rectangular function. However, this is only one function that produces the rectangular function as amplitude response. Supposing that you are only interested in the amplitude (absolute value) component of the Fourier transform being equal to the rectangular function (so the phase can be anything), what would be a general solution?
So, in equation:
$$
|h(\omega)| = \left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-2{\pi}i{\omega}t}\, dt\right|=A \cdot rect\left(\frac{\omega}{B}\right)
$$
With A and B real scale and rate parameters, (real) $ \omega $ angular frequency, and $ \left| g \right| $ the absolute value of complex value $ g $.
Does this have a general solution in closed form? Or, alternatively, a way to approach the problem numerically?

Hi: You may get more responses if you send to dsp.stackexchange.com. But, follow the posting guidelines because I know that double postings are frowned upon.

@Mark, thanks for the hint. Maybe I can remove this item to avoid double posting.

Hi Bottieres: Unfortunately, I'm not sure of the rules. If you remove the item, I don't know if that's okay ?

Note that $|h(\omega)|^2 = h(\omega)\overline{h(\omega)}$

There is no general form for this. To see this, let's consider the reverse:
$$\left| e^{i\ g(x)} \operatorname{Rect}(x) \right| = \left| e^{i g(x)} \right| \left|\operatorname{Rect}(x) \right| = \left|\operatorname{Rect}(x) \right|$$
Taking inverse fourier transform of $e^{i\ g(x)} \operatorname{Rect}(x)$,
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}[e^{i\ g(x)} \operatorname{Rect}(x)](\omega) = \operatorname{Sinc}(y) \overset{\omega}{\star} \mathcal{F}^{-1}[e^{i\ g(x)}](y)$$ where $\overset{\omega}{\star}$ is convolution with the delay/shift parmeter $\omega$
There is no general solution for $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[e^{i\ g(x)}](y)$. It depends on $g(x)$. So the resulting convolution cannot be fixed.

Wow, thanks for the reply! Isn't it possible to say anything about $k(t)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}e^{i\ g(x)}$?
Any condition or property for this function that allows bounded but otherwise free creation of a compliant waveform? I understand that what that the amplitude response of k(t) must be equal to 1 on the whole spectrum, so it is any impuls response of an all-pass filter?

I could not figure out any interesting patterns for varying $g(x)$. For example, if $g(x)=x$, you get your expected Dirac delta for IFT of cos and sin. For $g(x)= x^2$, IFT is in the same form, i e. $e^{I y^2}$. For $g(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x^4$, you start seeing more complex functions like Airy function and hypergeometric and gamma functions. You can imagine $g(x)$ as a Taylor series with $x^n$ terms and all these complicated functions showing up. I can't imagine the convolution to be of any simple form. I saw your question on DSP stack exchange and some good answers in terms of all pass analysis
